# Pass variable values in the RegExp Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to pass variable values ​​in the rule expression . Someone any way ?
like is :

```
var a = 'khuya'; var regex = /{a}/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var a = "khuya";
var regex = new RegExp( "{" + a + "}" );
```

Comment: But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript for more...